# Image atlas in QML

Tags: image, qt, qml, texture-atlas

I have an image like this one: 
http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/basics/result.gif
(it contains two rows of individual data: three square images in the upper row, and below another square and two 'empty' squares)

I want to use it inside a repeater, so that I get four image buttons, each with one of the subimages.

Is there a "texture-atlas" modules in QML?

I only found http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-sprite.html and I hope there is something that is better for my use-case.

Comment: I would do that using `QQuickImageProvider`

Comment: @folibis : Thanks for the idea, but is there any other method "not using C++" ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I said in comment I would do that using `QQuickImageProvider` since that's the fastest and the least memory intensive way. But QML is very flexible and you can do with it whatever you want. As for your question you can do as following:

***Tile.qml***

```
import QtQuick 2.9

Item {
    id: container
    property alias source: img.source
    property int cellWidth: 1
    property int cellHeight: 1
    property int slideIndex: 0
    clip: true
    Image {
        id: img
        property int cols: img.paintedWidth / container.cellWidth
        property int rows: img.paintedHeight / container.cellHeight
        x: -container.cellWidth * Math.floor(container.slideIndex % cols)
        y: -container.cellHeight * Math.floor(container.slideIndex / cols)
    }
}
```

and usage:

```
import QtQuick 2.9
import QtQuick.Window 2.2

Window {
    id: window
    title: "Test"
    visible: true
    width: 600
    height: 400

    Row {
        spacing: 10
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        Repeater {
            model: 4
            Tile {
                width: 32
                height: 32
                cellWidth: 32
                cellHeight: 32
                slideIndex: index
                source: "http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/basics/result.gif"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The idea is to wrap the entire image into a container and clip it appropriately. Here I use index-based access to a slide, you can do that as you want.

Comment: sorry, I missunderstood the upper comment, tought you meant the C++ implementation itself. Many thanks for the examplecode! Looks like this is what I was looking for

Comment: Yes, I meant C++ ie. custom implementation of `QQuickImageProvider`. So you will be able to manage the image more more practical. In QML implementation above you hold big image to just show part of that. Rest of image is unnecessary. Therefore, this implementation requires more memory. But that doesn't matter if you don;t have hundreds of such items.

Comment: an alternative would be to use a single `Image` and multiple `ShaderEffectSource` with the `sourceRect` property on the correct region of the `Image`.